# Variable inside Module keeps on returning undefined

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I want to modify variable currentPlayer each turn. I have added PlayerController.switchPlayer() to an event listener as well. But every time currentPlayer fails to get updated and returns undefined. I even tried moving the same variable to global as an undefined and still it will fail to get updated despite the code running through the whole if/else block.

```js
const PlayerController = (() => {
  let playerO = Player("O");
  let playerX = Player("X");
  let currentPlayer;
  let switchPlayer = () => {
    if (!playerO.activePlayer) {
      playerO.activePlayer = true;
      playerX.activePlayer = false;
      currentPlayer = playerO;
    } else if (playerO.activePlayer && !playerX.activePlayer) {
      playerX.activePlayer = true;
      playerO.activePlayer = false;
      currentPlayer = playerX;
    }
  };
  return { playerO, playerX, switchPlayer, currentPlayer };
})();
```

Comment: How are you calling `switchPlayer`? And how are you checking `currentPlayer` after calling `switchPlayer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object to be returned is calculated *once* - at the end of the IIFE. Calling `switchPlayer` and reassigning the local `currentPlayer` does not change the returned object with the `currentPlayer` property, because the object has already been evaluated and returned.

You could make `currentPlayer` into a getter instead, so that it returns the possibly-reassigned value inside the IIFE:

```
return {
  playerO,
  playerX,
  switchPlayer,
  get currentPlayer() {
    return currentPlayer;
  }
};
```

But I'd prefer to not hide the fact that it's a function, so that you call `getCurrentPlayer` from the outside.

```
return {
  playerO,
  playerX,
  switchPlayer,
  getCurrentPlayer: () => currentPlayer
};
```